# How to send and retrieve data from web service using PHP and Android

Tags: php, android, xml, encoding

I am developing an application in which I am getting data from web service and displaying in the Android mobile. But the problem is while getting Turkish data it is not displaying correctly.

I already set `utf-8` in PHP. But still getting special character symbols like `A?&#305;k ?&#287` for the string `Açık Öğretim`.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include("Netbrut_class.php");
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset: utf-8');

    $webservice = new Netbrut;

    $content='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><salary_comparision>';

    $education = $webservice->select_education();

    for($i=0; $i<count($education); $i++){

        $string = html_entity_decode($education[$i]['comparision_name'], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
        $content.="<education id='".$education[$i]['id']."'>".$string."</education>";
    }

    $content .='</salary_comparision>';

echo $content;
?>
```

And my Java code is / Here I am writing java code just for testing:

```
public class testing {

    static String[] attributes;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.106/netBrut/webservices/testing.php");

        HttpURLConnection  connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        java.io.InputStream is  = connection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8");


        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        char [] buffer = new char[1024 * 8];
        int count ;

        while( (count = reader.read(buffer)) != -1){
          sw.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        System.out.println(sw.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

And returning XML from web service is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<salary_comparision>
    <education id='128'>A?&#305;k ?&#287;retim</education>//Check here
    <education id='5'>Doktora</education>
    <education id='3'>Master</education>
    <education id='4'>MBA</education>
    <education id='2'>?niversite</education>
</salary_comparision>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Php code just change the below lines

```
 $string = html_entity_decode($education[$i]['comparision_name'], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
 $content.="<education id='".$education[$i]['id']."'>".$string."</education>";
```

to

```
$string = $webservice->unhtmlspecialchars($education[$i]['comparision_name']);
$content.="<education id='".$education[$i]['id']."'>".$string."</education>";
```

See [`htmlspecialchars`<sup>­*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).